# Sum values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I'm working with an Excel file and openpyxl.

Below is sample data:

```
Name    Value
Amy1    4
Bob1    5
Bob1    5
Bob2    8
Chris1  7
Chris2  3
Chris3  6
Chris3  6
Chris3  6
```

Using the for loop below, I grab the value associated with each unique name.

```
for rowNum in range(2, 11):
    person = sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 13).value
    people.append(person)
    personValue.update({person: sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 26).value})
```

That yields a dictionary with a single entry for each name (Amy1, Bob1, Bob2, etc.).

I want to merge and sum the value for each matching name to return the following result:

```
Name  Value
Amy   4
Bob   13
Chris 16
```

Comment: Use a defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method to set a default value for a key and then add to it that way.

Since all of your keys are in the format name#, you can get the end result you want like this:

```
mergedResult = dict()

for name in startingDict:
    mergedResult[name[:-1]] = mergedResult.get(name[:-1], 0) + startingDict[name]
```

Here, the `get()` method checks for a key `name[:-1]` (the name from your starting dictionary without the final character) in your result dictionary. If that key isn't present, it adds it with a default value of 0 and returns that value. If that key is already present, it simply returns the corresponding value. Then, the value from your starting dictionary is added to the value in your result dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If `name = sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 13).value`

And `value =  sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 26).value`

Edited according to your comments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

people = defaultdict(int)
category = defaultdict(int)

for rowNum in range(2, 11):
    # Name with number
    person = sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 13).value
    # Name without number
    category_name = ''.join([c for c in person if not c.isdigit()])
    people[person] += sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 26).value
    category[category_name] += sheet.cell(row = rowNum, column = 26).value
```

Result - people:

```
Name    Value
Amy1    4
Bob1    10
Bob2    8
Chris1  7
Chris2  3
Chris3  18
```

Result - category:

```
Name    Value
Amy     4
Bob     18
Chris   28
```

This will work.

Thanks Padraic Cunningham.
I just realized what i misunderstood.

Comment: You are completely missing the whole point of using a defauldict

Comment: This totals up all the values and results in 

Name  Value
Amy    4
Bob    18
Chris  28

Comment: (Whoops, meant to add more to that comment).

Comment: I need it to only measure each value (Amy1, Bob1, Bob2) once and then sum the values of each of those into one category (Bob1 + Bob2 + Bob3 = 13).